# Logistic Regression - negative coefficient, categorical variables

Tags: logistic-regression, coefficients

I am trying to build attrition model and have these variables :- 10 categorical variables with sub levels which created into dummy variables and 4 continuous variables in a trained data set. My Y dependent variable is binary variable.

After running log regress, the results are some of the dummy variables are found to have collinearity error and some of them are insignificant. Tried running penalized log reg, same results obtained. After omitting the dummy variables, I run a new log regress, there are negative coefficients in the 3 continuous variables which are found significant. But, they are in a very small numbers e.g. -0.003,-0.005 etc which did not make sense. Now I am in a fix.

Is there any method to handle the categorical variables as it is strange that all of them are not significant? Are there any methods which are more suitable to handle this situation?

All advises appreciated!

*A repost.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with programming, though. Why SO? Why not Stats?

Comment: I'm sure that logistic regression is a binary classifier...why use that with many categories? Use a neural net, a SVM (one-vs-all) or naive bayes.

Comment: Hi, I was given the data set in this way. @Roope : sorry, I may get your question incorrectly. Are you referring to the Stata program?

Comment: Hi, @BastianSchoettle: Initially, because I used leaving and staying as the Y dependent variable and I need to find out who are the key variables among these variables. This is the first time that I encountered many categorical variables in a data set. May I know what is SVM?

Comment: So is it for a project for university or anything or could you just choose a different algorithm to solve your problem? Maybe, Support Vector Machines are quite good :)

Comment: Thanks!it is not for university project. Yes, I could chose any other methods. I just done a quick read about support vector machines. The maths part looks like do not handle well with  binary numbers? As I have changed all the categorical variables into dummy coding.

Comment: @user149635 I was referring to stats.stackexchange.com (i.e. Cross Validated). You'll get more help with statistics there, whereas Stack Overflow is a programming question site.